# Doubly Linked List

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Explain how to implement doubly linked lists using only one pointer value np[x] per item instead of the usual two (next and prev). Assume that all pointer values can be interpreted as k-bit integers, and def ine np[x] to be np[x] = next[x] XOR prev[x], the k-bit "exclusive-or" ofnext[x] and prev[x]. (The value NIL is represented by 0.) Be sure to describe what information is needed to access the head of the list. Show how to implement the SEARCH, INSERT, and DELETE operations on such a list. Also show how to reverse such a list in O(1) time.

Source: CLRS 10.2-8 of Cormen Third Edition

PS: This is not a homework question. I am practicing/revising data structures.

Comment: Typing **doubly linked list one pointer XOR** into Google points you to the Wikipedia article that totally answers this question.

Comment: *Explain how to implement doubly linked lists using only one pointer value np[x] per item instead of the usual two (next and prev)*.  no! you're not my mom!

Comment: I thought it was a tough question!
I already came up with this answer but looked too "easy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the pointer as a 'regular' integer. So, you can do any integer operations on it, including xor.

For each node, store `xorValue = next ^ previous`.

Why is it helpful?

If you are iterating from front to end - you know where `previous` is, and you have its value, so you can get next with `next = xorValue ^ previous`.

Same idea applies when iterating from last to first: `previous = xorValue ^ next`.

This is enough since you cannot reach any place in the linked list without iterating from last to first or first to last - so the value of `previous` OR `next` is known to you, and as we have seen - it is all you need in order to get the other one.

Based on this you can create (c-like **Pseudo code**):

```
struct Node { 
   void* data;
   int xorValue;
}
Node* next(Node* node, void* previous) { 
    return (Node*)(node->xorValue ^ (int)previous));
}
Node* previous(Node* node, void* next) { 
    return (Node*)(node->xorValue ^ (int)next));
}
```

For the head/last elements  - regard the previous/next value (correspondingly) as simply NULL (0),  and store the next element as it is. It works since `next ^ 0 = next`

Comment: hah!
I can do it this way!
But the point is we need to know the previous or the next to get to traverse the list. So what is the point?
Basically we require two pointers to traverse!

Comment: @ManasPaldhe The point is - you know these pointers, since you are iterating the list somehow. Also, remembering the "last" pointer is only one integer, while storing both `prev` and `next` is `n` integers (pointers), you save `O(n)` space doing so.